# Android service stops when app is stopped

Tags: java, android, android-service

From the `onStartCommand` in my service I spawn a thread that begins a very long download process. The problem is that when the user closes the app through the multitasking screen (and they do sometimes), the download thread stops running too.

A while after it stops, the service's `onCreate` is being called again if I return START_NOT_STICKY in `onStartCommand`, and is also restarted with a null intent if I return START_STICKY in `onStartCommand`.

I figured that if I return `START_CONTINUATION_MASK` in `onStartCommand` the download thread won't stop when the app is closed through the multitasking screen. But I don't feel like I can trust this flag because I can't find any recommendation to use it.

I don't need to ensure my service will run forever with startForeground, I just need it to keep running after the app is closed at least in most cases (as long as the OS isn't in extreme memory conditions).

What should I do?